# Oriented bounding box in SymPy

Tags: sympy, bounding-box

I use SymPy's geometry module for geometric stuff. I need OBBs but so far I could not came across this feature in SymPy. Does SymPy really provide OBBs? If not is there a module to download as I do not want to re-code.